# Express using a patternless dynamic base URL to render different pages

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, express

I am interested in having a route that could respond to a request with a file eg express's `res.sendFile()` based on the URL's base parameter i.e. `www.example.com/:parameter`. The problem is that the URLs are completely user generated and completely dynamic. Similar to that of Github, `www.github.com/username` could render a user's profile or `www.github.com/project` could render a project—but they are both strings that don't have a pattern and the machine has no way of knowing that www.github.com/username refers to a user view unless it does some type of check.

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
res.sendfile('index.html', { root: config.server.distFolder });
```

Github responds to server requests with different views based on the parameter, even though they have no predefined pattern.

i.e. it would be easy to know that www.github.com/user/username is a user route and the server can respond with a user view (the pattern to match would be `www.github.com/user/:user` But when the string is completely dynamic it becomes more difficult. (How does express know if it should respond with a user or a project view with a url like `example.com/cococola`)?

I believe you would somehow be able to check the URL parameter, understand that it refers to (in this case) either a project or a user's page, and then render that view. How do you do this without making a synchronous call and forcing the user to wait for the server to check what view-type the parameter string refers to before responding?

I'm using angular, are there other ways to respond to server requests with different pages based on URL's that have no predeterminable matching pattern? The reason being that, I would like to separate my site into many different apps. www.example.com/username might require a user's profile SPA, whereas www.example.com/projectname might require a user's project SPA—but, as these are user defined, there is no way to respond based on the parameter's matching pattern. Would like to keep the URL as minimal as possible :-)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :-)

Comment: Just use a database / some kind of key value store where the key is the url parameter and the value is the view type. Then you just need to do a simple lookup.

Comment: Perfect! I guess I was thinking about it wrong. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a database / some kind of key value store where the key is the url parameter and the value is the view type. Then you just need to do a simple lookup.

Comment: Is this considered good practice? If the DB is hosted externally then the client will have to wait for another round-trip request. Maybe it's only good practice if the infrastructure is set up correctly? (i.e. low latency between the server and the db?) Thanks for the help.